# Ruby on Rails error after 'rails new' command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I was trying to create program with Ruby on Rails but when I entered `rails new` command it gave me following output:

```
[DEPRECATED] `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`. If you instead want the environment before bundler was originally loaded, use `Bundler.with_original_env` (called at /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:416)
Traceback (most recent call last):
/usr/bin/ruby2.7: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Traceback (most recent call last):
/usr/bin/ruby2.7: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

I am creating this program under WSL Ubuntu distro. Do you know how can I resolve this problem ? Thanks for answers and adivces

**EDIT**
*I run* `bundle exec spring binstub --all`it gave me output:

```
/mnt/c/Ruby31-x64/bin/bundle: line 6: /mnt/c/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

**rails -v** gave me output: `Rails 5.2.3`

**ruby -v** gave me output: `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

Comment: add the version of ruby and the version of rails to the question

Comment: Did you try to run `bundle exec spring binstub --all`? And what is the output of `rails -v` and `ruby -v` commands in your terminal?

Comment: @Josien I added versions of ruby and rails into question and also output of that command

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have some combination of Ruby, Rails and Bundler on your system that do not play nice together. There are a few things you can try. Don't do them all at the same time, but one by one, and check after each thing what the result is of `rails new`.

- Upgrade your Rails version. The [current version of Rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) at this time is 7.0.2.4. Using a new Rails could be the easiest and cleanest way to 'fix' this problem. To upgrade, you can run `gem install rails` in your terminal, and that should automatically get you the most current version of Rails. Check the version after installation with `rails -v`.
- Fix your Ruby version(s). I am not sure what Rubies are installed on your system, but it seems weird that your system Ruby is 2.7, but `bundle exec` tries to do something with Ruby 3.1 (`/mnt/c/Ruby31-x64/bin/bundle`)? It might help to use a Ruby versioning tool like [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) so you can be VERY sure of the Ruby you are using.
- Downgrade your Bundler version. The [deprecation warning](https://bundler.io/v2.1/whats_new.html) you're getting is added in v2.1 as far as I can see, so getting a lower Bundler version *might* help. Get the version before 2.1 with `gem install bundler:2.0.2`. Check the version after installation with `bundler -v`. I am not a fan of this option, so please only try if all else fails.

I hope one of these options helps you!

#### Edit

I missed the `windows-subsystem-for-linux` tag. I have no experience with WSL, and this could well be related. My answer might not be very useful to you, sorry.